# Percent-encoding of asterisks (*) in links

Tags: bug, status-completed, links

In [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35601/24166) I linked a URL that contains a `*` character:

`http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://www.alexa.com/topsites`

The `*` char seems to be converted to `%2a`. When I click this link, I get the following error:

> HTTP Status 404 - `/web/%2a/http://www.alexa.com/topsites`
>
> type Status report
>
> message `/web/%2a/http://www.alexa.com/topsites`
>
> description The requested resource (`/web/%2a/http://www.alexa.com/topsites`) is not available.

Reloading doesn't help, but when I switch to the URL bar and press enter again (or when I re-type the `*` in the URL), the page loads. So it seems to me that the `*` should not be percent-encoded.

Also, the detection of the link doesn't work correctly, as you can see here:

> http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://www.alexa.com/topsites

(it recognizes only the part before the `*` character as link)

---

The `*` is a `reserved` character (`sub-delims`), according to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986):

> URIs that differ in the replacement of a reserved character with its
> corresponding percent-encoded octet are not equivalent.  **Percent-
> encoding a reserved character**, or decoding a percent-encoded octet
> that corresponds to a reserved character, **will change how the URI is
> interpreted by most applications**.  Thus, characters in the reserved
> set are protected from normalization and are therefore safe to be
> used by scheme-specific and producer-specific algorithms for
> delimiting data subcomponents within a URI.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159551/chat-markdown-do-not-parse-links-or-tags-with-an-asterisk-in-them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build; for details see [my answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220324/problem-with-clickable-archive-org-urls/236348#236348).